# Use of Tonelli's Theorem to calculate $\int_{[0,\infty[} (\int_{[0,\infty[}xe^{-x^{2}(1+y^{2})}d\lambda (x)) d\lambda (y)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Define $f: [0,\infty[\times [0,\infty[ \to \bar{\mathbb R}$, $f(x,y):= xe^{-x^{2}(1+y^{2})}$ it is clear that $f(x,y)\geq 0$ $\lambda-$a.e. Therefore, Tonelli's theorem holds. This means:

$\int_{[0,\infty[} (\int_{[0,\infty[}xe^{-x^{2}(1+y^{2})}d\lambda (x)) d\lambda (y)=\int_{[0,\infty[} (\int_{[0,\infty[}xe^{-x^{2}(1+y^{2})}d\lambda (y)) d\lambda (x)$

Looking exclusively at $\int_{[0,\infty[}xe^{-x^{2}(1+y^{2})}d\lambda (y)$, the only thing that comes to mind is "Riemann Integration", namely:

$\int_{[0,\infty[}xe^{-x^{2}(1+y^{2})}d\lambda (y)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{[0,n]}xe^{-x^{2}(1+y^{2})}dy=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{-x\times2y}e^{-x^2(1+y^2)}\vert_{0}^{n}$

Which gets me stuck as I have a $y$ in the denominator, however, I see no other way of doing it. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you integrate over $y$ first, then it gives $\frac{1}{2x}I$ where $I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}dt$ is the Gaussian integral.

Comment: Why $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-t^{2}}dt$ and not $\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-t^{2}}dt$?

Comment: The factor $1/2$ is in front.  Typically Gaussian integral refers to the former.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Lebesgue  integral agrees with the Riemann integral if we have absolutely Riemann-integrable functions we can first integrate with respect to $x$ to get:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x^2(1+y^2)}d\lambda(x) = \frac{-1}{2}\frac{e^{-x^2(1+y^2)}}{1+y^2}\Big\vert_{0}^{\infty} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+y^2}.$$

Now integrate

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+y^2}d\lambda(y)$$

NOTE: A primitive for $xe^{-x^2(1+y^2)}$ with respect to $y$ is not given by $\frac{1}{-x^2\cdot 2y}e^{-xy^2}$! Rather

$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dy}\frac{1}{2y}e^{-x^2y^2} = \frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{-2yx^2e^{-x^2y^2}(2y)-2e^{-x^2y^2}}{4y^2}=-xe^{-x^2y^2}-\frac{e^{-x^2y^2}}{2xy^2}$$

Comment: How can this help me find $\int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-t^{2}}d \lambda (t)$ ?

Comment: Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, that is why I needed to use Tonelli, to switch integrals, and integrate with respect to $y$